# "Who" nominal relative clauses as subject

Tags: relative-clauses

What difference in terms of usage and style would there be between the following sentences:

1. Those who came yesterday have already left
2. **Who** came yesterday have already left
3. The ones who came yesterday have already left

Comment: *Those who* is perfect. Just *who* sounds wrong to me. *The ones who* is correct, but should only be used in certain contexts, I'd say, not as a general alternative to *those who*.

Comment: How do you like

**Who should run the business is me.**

Comment: I'm afraid that still sounds wrong. You can only use *who* without an explicit antecedent if it introduces an indirect question, I should say—not a relative clause as here. *I don't know who did it* (indirect question).

Comment: A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, 15.9:
_Nonspecific **who** is occasionally found in nominal relative clauses that are not functioning as subject complement_

Comment: Does it have any examples? Does it consider indirect questions relative clauses?

Answer (score 1):

Those who/ The ones who/ All who/ Everyone who/ People who/ Nobody who/ One person who/ Millions who/ The better ones who/ The ones I remember who/

All these are possible, but what you can't say is simply 'Who came yesterday...'

The principle applies to all sorts of things:

Those who came yesterday/ those who are still drinking/ those who are unaccompanied/ those who are wearing shoes/ etc.

Comment: What do you think of what's written in _A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language_?

Comment: I'm trying to picture a 'nominal relative clause'containing 'who', 'not functioning as subject complement'. Can you give me an example of such a sentence, please?

Comment: **Who should run the business is me.**
(A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, 15.9)

Comment: **Who chooseth me shall gain what many men desire**
(The Merchant of Venice)

Comment: @Runglish I am not going to argue with Shakespeare but I have the sense that the translators of the Bible of the same period might have said 'Whosoever chooseth me...'. In modern English I would not say 'Who should run the business is me'. That is not to say it is wrong!  I might say 'He who should run the business is me'.